# Any precision loss when converting float64 to uint64 in C? assuming only the whole number part of the data is meaningful

Tags: c, binary, primitive-types

I have a counter field from one TCP protocol which keeps track of samples sent out. It is defined as float64. I need to translate this protocol to a different one, in which the counter is defined as uint64.

Can I safely store the float64 value in the uint64 without losing any precision on the whole number part of the data? Assuming the fractional part can be ignored.

EDIT: Sorry if I didn't describe it clearly. There is no code. I'm just looking at two different protocol documentations to see if one can be translated to the other.

Please treat float64 as double, the documentation isn't well written and is pretty old.

Many thanks.

Comment: There is no `float64` type in C. And please be more precise. Show your code.

Comment: What kind of maniac uses floating-point types for counters?

Comment: It's from an old firm in the defense industry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking about 64 bit floating point values such as IEEE Binary64 as documented in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format .

Converting a `double` represented as a 64 bit IEEE floating point value to a `uint64_t` will not lose any precision on the integral part of the value, as long as the value itself is non negative and less than **2<sup>64</sup>**. But if the value is larger than 2<sup>53</sup>, the representation as a `double` does not allow complete precision, so whatever computation led to the value probably was inaccurate anyway.

Note that the reverse is false, IEEE floats have less precision than 64 bit `uint64_t`, so close but different large values will convert to the same `double` values.

Note that a counter implemented as a 64 bit `double` is intrinsically limited by the precision of the floating point type. Incrementing a value larger than 2<sup>53</sup> by one is likely to have no effect at all.  Using a floating point type to implement a packet counter seems a very bad idea. Using a `uint64_t` counter directly seem a safer bet.  You only have to worry about wrap around at 2<sup>64</sup>, a condition that you can check for in the unlikely case where you would actually expect to count that far.

If you cannot change the format, verify that the floating point value is within range for the conversion and store an appropriate value if it is not:

```
#include <stdint.h>

...

double v = get_64bit_value();
uint64_t result;

if (v < 0) {
    result = 0;
} else
if (v >= (double)UINT64_MAX) {
    result = UINT64_MAX;
} else {
    result = (uint64_t)v;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean 2^53?

Comment: Technically, if the value is larger than 2^53 and less than 2^64, precision is already lost in the floating point type. The conversion is not causing the loss.

Comment: The `if (v > (double)UINT64_MAX)`-test is likely insufficient. Note that `UINT64_MAX` has all bits set, so every right-shift of it is odd. Consequently, converting to `double` will round *up* in default round-to-nearest-**even**-mode. You see where this is going?

Comment: I see. The number of item to be counted won't go over 2^53 in our application. Thank you!

Comment: @EOF: I guess converting `UINT64_MAX` to `double` would yield `0x1p64`, so the comparison must definitely be `>=`. Thank you.

Comment: @KKsan: it actually depends how you count them, if you increment one by one, the count cannot go past 2^53, if you add a chunk at a time, the total count would be inaccurate but may reach larger values.

Comment: Rather than `v >= (double)UINT64_MAX` code should functionally be `v >= (double)(UINT64_MAX + 1)`.  Of course `UINT64_MAX + 1` likely wraps to 0.  Alternative: `#define DBL_UINT64_MAX_P1 ((UINT64_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)) if (v >= DBL_UINT64_MAX_P1) Handle_Overflow();`  For me, I do not trust the rounding of `(double)UINT64_MAX` and prefer exact values.

Comment: Further `if (v < 0) { result = 0;` is right is code is to limit, but not if code is to detect. Better to use `if (v <= -1.0) Handle_Underflow();`.  The range of allowable `double` to `uint_64t` is _slightly larger_ than `[0...UINT64_MAX]`.  It is `[-0.999 ... UINT64_MAX+0.999]`.  (NaN need additional consideration)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, precision is lost. Negative numbers cannot be converted properly to uint64 (as this type is unsigned), as well as numbers greater than 2^64-1. In all other cases, the conversion is exact (providing you look at the float64 value as exact and rounding is done correctly).

Comment: If the floating point value is a *count*, there is no way you can have numbers larger than 2^53. After that point, increment becomes a nop. Likewise I would not expect counts to be negative.

Comment: Precision is not lost, a conversion error may occur if the value is out of range, which is another issue with worse consequences.

Comment: @R.. Detail: Depending on rounding (e.g round nearest - ties to even) , 2^53 + 1 _may_ go to 2^53 + 2.  So increment is not a nop, but likely faulty for code's operation.  After that things, may get to 2^54 before becoming a nop.  IAC, a FP increment count is unwise.

Comment: Detail: "Negative numbers cannot be converted properly to uint64" is mostly correct.  (-1.0 ... -0.0] correctly convert to `uint64_t 0`.

Comment: Detail: Like-wise "numbers greater than 2^64-1" should be "numbers as great as 2^64".  Conversion to `unsigned` truncates toward zero. So non-whole number values in the range (2^64-1 ... 2^64) are OK.